# ASP.NET - running a bat script on another machine

Tags: asp.net, scripting, batch-file

I would like to run a bat script on one of the machines on the domain, from my asp.net application. Machine with the batch script is a temporary storage machine, and script synchronizes it with the permanent storage machine. So, what is the optimal way of doing this?

The thing I tried is to use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run a script on the remote machine. I create  a process that makes a PsExec call, and it actually does it's job pretty well. However, since the ASP.NET worker thread runs under ASP.NET account that has restricted privileges, I must hard-code my domain user credentials in PsExec call, and that's something I do not like doing.

Is there a way to overcome this problem, or maybe some other approach that I could try?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <identity impersonate="true" /> setting in your Web.config to have the application run under the IUSR, or you can set a username/password on the identity tag to an account you'd like to use to run the BAT file.

I had previously found some details on Impersonate over at: http://www.aspdev.org/articles/web.config/

But I'm sure a quick web search will find you even more info on Impersonate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above doesn't work. New processes will be spawned by default under the ASP.NET account.

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889251.

"To spawn a process that runs under the context of the impersonated user, you cannot use the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method. This is because in ASP.NET, impersonation is performed at the thread level and not at the process level. Therefore, any process that you spawn from ASP.NET will run under the context of the ASP.NET worker process and not under the impersonated context."